# Docker image ran for Django but cannot access dev server url

Tags: python, django, docker

Working on containerizing my server. I believe I successfully run build, when I run docker-compose my development server appears to run, but when I try to visit the associated dev server URL:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

However, I get a page with the error:

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

These are the settings on my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR C:/Users/15512/Desktop/django-project/peerplatform
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--settings=signup.settings"]
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "49153:6379"
  pairprogramming_be:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./signup/.env
      - ./payments/.env
      - ./.env
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8001"
    container_name: "pairprogramming_be"
    volumes:
      - "C:/Users/15512/Desktop/django-project/peerplatform://pairprogramming_be"
    working_dir:
      "/C:/Users/15512/Desktop/django-project/peerplatform"
```

This is the .env file:

```
DEBUG=1
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=0.0.0.0
```

FYI: the redis image runs successfully. This is what I have tried:

- I tried changing the allowed hosts to localhost and 127.0.0.0.1
- I tried running the command `python manage.py runserver` and eventually added `0.0.0.0:8000`
- When I run `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }} pairprogramming_be` I get a blank response/my docker container doesn't appear to have an IP Address

Answer (score 0):

where is the `8001` port taken from? this is the internal (expected) listening port. Since you set your application (inside docker) to listen on `8000`, you should map it from `8000` to anything else..

just change compose to:

```
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: @Emm did you try that?

Comment: Yeah. Still getting the same issue

Comment: With 0.0.0.0 right? Anything special in the app logs?

Comment: Nothing special in the app logs